# Configure FastCGI for Python

Tags: python, fastcgi, trac

I have nginx running on a VM and I want to run a Trac site. I need to run a python FastCGI server, but I cannot tell which is *the* server to use. I have found the following:

- [Lighttpd spawn-fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) But this seems to require that you compile lighttpd just to get the fcgi server, which is weird.
- [fcgi.py](http://svn.saddi.com/py-lib/trunk/fcgi.py) But this one seems to be deprecated. At the very least it is poorly documented.
- [flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup) This one comes with dependencies on ubuntu (python-cheetah{a} python-mysqldb{a} python-webpy{a}) that seem unnecessary. Also poorly documented.

Are there any recent guides for setting this up? [Trac's own FastCGI setup page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFastCgi#SimpleNginxConfiguration) seems to miss some steps.

Answer (score 3):

`trac` should be now WSGI compliant, so you can use any supported method to run the site. If it is a low traffic site, you can always use CGI, and eventually move to something else later if you need it. For the other methods, use `mod_wsgi` or install `flup` for FCGI (even if it installed extra dependencies).

To use `flup`, you have to import the appropriate WSGI server, then run it, i.e.

```
from flup.server.fcgi_fork import WSGIServer
def main_app(...):
  ...

WSGIServer(main_app).run()
```

If you want to run it as external server (i.e. not started by the web server), substitute this:

```
WSGIServer(main_app,bindAddress=('1.2.3.4',9999)).run()
```

Comment: See above regarding mod_wsgi (unmaintained, webserver running multiple different scripting engines).
I cannot find any documentation on how to setup flup, do you have any guides.
As far as I can tell, Nginx doesn't just run CGI, it needs a (Fast)CGI server to run the scripts.

Comment: Added to the answer for formatting.

Comment: Rob. I think you will find from most people the suggestion is to use Apache/mod_wsgi more so than nginx/mod_wsgi. The Apache/mod_wsgi is definitely not 'unmaintained' and has copious amounts of documentation to go with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well man, flup is used by Django itself. Its an awesome method to run python fastcgi applications unless you have a mod_wsgi or something similar.

The code to run flup is:

```
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

def app(environ, start_response):
  start_respone('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
  yield "Hello World"

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Comment: And yeah, I don't think flup has any dependencies, I installed it recently without any. I'm on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Why FastCGI in particular?  In Python, there's a standard interface for writing web server apps, called WSGI.  Various servers provide frameworks for doing this; eg, `mod_wsgi` for Apache.  For nginx, there appears to be:
  http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxNgxWSGIModule
which is even based on mod_wsgi.

Comment: The nginx/mod_wsgi can't really be said to be based on Apache/mod_wsgi. The author of nginx/mod_wsgi looked at Apache/mod_wsgi, used similar concepts and configuration naming for parts, but because the internals of nginx are quite different to Apache, the code is pretty well all new. Just be careful about what you use nginx/mod_wsgi for as the use of an underyling event based web server raises problems in multi process configurations where you have a blocking WSGI on top. Read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html'.

Comment: @Phil: WSGI is a common interface for all methods for dynamic content, be it CGI, FCGI, SCGI or an apache module (mod_wsgi, which replace mod_python). In fact `flup` provides a WSGI server, with FCGI connection mechanism.

Comment: @Phil, it doesn't seem that this module has been actively developed in quiet awhile. I am running a web server with PHP, Python & Perl scripts. To me it makes more sense to use FastCGI instead of modules given my low memory VM setup.

Comment: @Dan my issue with flup is that it is completely undocumented. I do not know what flup is nor how to use it. Relying on undocumented hobby software scares me. Tomorrow the guy could take his code down and replace it with LOLCats.

Comment: @Graham: per the URL I gave, the design was influenced by, and it borrows code from, mod_wsgi.  I guess "based on" was too strong a statement.  Sorry.

@Dan-Andreatta: I know how they relate; it's just that FastCGI seemed to be an overly strong requirements statement, given the presented problem, and designing to work with WSGI is, IMO, the way to go.

@Rob: okay, the existing use of FastCGI for other languages is sufficient cause to stick to a common platform.  :)